# C# async client not receiving data

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, client

I've used the code from [codeguru](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_misc/sampleprograms/article.php/c7695/Asynchronous-Socket-Programming-in-C-Part-I.htm) and revised it to put the necessary async functions under classes to abstract it from the main program. I did so since our main program will be doing more than async communication; it involves database also but it is not the scope of my work for the project. Anyway, the sample codes for client and server from the site use WinForms. In my implementation, the client is in console (because it will be run on Raspberry Pi as a microcontroller) while server is still in WinForms (PC).

I couldn't get the client to receive data. There are no errors though saying that the client and server are not connected.

Here's the class that handles async functions for the client.

```
// ClientSocket.cs
namespace Server.Networking
{
    public class ClientSocket
    {
        byte[] _dataBuffer = new byte[10];
        private IAsyncResult _result;
        private AsyncCallback _pfnCallBack;
        public Socket _clientSocket;
        public string ipAddress; // = "192.168.1.101";
        public int port; // = 151;
        public string received = string.Empty;
        public bool hasReceived = false;

        public void ConnectToServer(string ipAddress, int port)
        {
            try
            {
                // Create the socket instance
                _clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

                // Create the remote IP address
                IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse(ipAddress);

                // Create the end point 
                IPEndPoint ipEnd = new IPEndPoint(ip, port);

                // Connect to the remote host
                _clientSocket.Connect(ipEnd);
                if (_clientSocket.Connected)
                {
                    //Wait for data asynchronously 
                    WaitForData();
                }
            }
            #region catch
            catch (SocketException socketEx)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Connection failed. Check if the server is running.\n\nError message: {0}", socketEx);
            }
            #endregion
        }

        public void SendMessage(string dataToSend)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] byData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dataToSend);
                if (_clientSocket != null)
                {
                    _clientSocket.Send(byData);
                }
            }
            #region catch
            catch (SocketException socketEx)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Connection failed. Check if the server is running.\n\nError message: {0}", socketEx);
            }
            #endregion
        }

        public void WaitForData()
        {
            try
            {
                if (_pfnCallBack == null)
                {
                    _pfnCallBack = new AsyncCallback(OnDataReceived);
                }
                SocketPacket theSocPkt = new SocketPacket();
                theSocPkt.thisSocket = _clientSocket;
                // Start listening to the data asynchronously
                _result = _clientSocket.BeginReceive(theSocPkt.dataBuffer, 0, theSocPkt.dataBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, _pfnCallBack, theSocPkt);
            }
            #region catch
            catch (SocketException socketEx)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Connection failed. Check if the server is running.\n\nError message: {0}", socketEx);
            }
            #endregion
        }

        private void OnDataReceived(IAsyncResult asyn)
        {
            try
            {
                SocketPacket theSockId = (SocketPacket)asyn.AsyncState;
                int iRx = theSockId.thisSocket.EndReceive(asyn);
                char[] chars = new char[iRx + 1];
                System.Text.Decoder d = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
                int charLen = d.GetChars(theSockId.dataBuffer, 0, iRx, chars, 0);
                System.String szData = new System.String(chars);
                hasReceived = true;
                received = szData;
                hasReceived = false;
                WaitForData();
            }
            #region catch
            catch (ObjectDisposedException objDispEx)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error messsage: {0}", objDispEx);
                System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Log(0, "1", "\nOnDataReceived: Socket has been closed\n");
            }
            catch (SocketException socketEx)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Connection failed. Check if the server is running.\n\nError message: {0}", socketEx);
            }
            #endregion 
        }

        public void DisconnectFromServer()
        {
            try
            {
                if (_clientSocket != null)
                {
                    _clientSocket.Close();
                    _clientSocket = null;
                }
            }
            #region catch
            catch (Exception stopConEx)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error message: {0}", stopConEx);
            }
            #endregion
        }
```

Here's my main program.

```
namespace Server
{
    public static class Program
    {
        public static ClientSocket _client = new ClientSocket();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            _client.ipAddress = "192.168.1.101";
            _client.port = 151;
            string messageToSend = string.Empty;

            Console.WriteLine("Connecting to server with IP Address {0} at port {1}.", _client.ipAddress, _client.port);

            _client.ConnectToServer(_client.ipAddress, _client.port);

            if (!_client._clientSocket.Connected)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Cannot connect to server.");
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    while (_client._clientSocket.Connected)
                    {
                        if (_client.hasReceived)
                            Console.WriteLine("Message from server: {0}", _client.received);
                    }
                }
                #region catch
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error message: {0}", ex);
                }
                #endregion
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For simplification purposes I let the client receive data only because I have issues with sending. Anyway, here are some of the modifications I've implemented from the original code when it comes to receiving data in the client side.

- From the original code (which is also reflected in `ClientSocket.cs` above), there are no 'special' calls to `WaitForData()`. By 'special' calls, I mean threading. Running that, the client still can't receive data. And so I've tried implementing threading it inside the class `ClientSocket`, but with no luck. With `Thread.isAlive` property, while debugging, I have seen that the thread stops without me explicitly saying in my code to stop the thread. It does so when I'm trying to send data from the server. Even threading it inside my main program doesn't work.
- I've added variables `public bool hasReceived` and `public string received`. With `hasReceived`, I wanted to be notified that the code is already inside `private void OnDataReceived(IAsyncResult asyn)` and it has received the data. `received` stores the data received. So far `hasReceived` has been only returning false due to the client program not receiving data.

With all these, can you see why my client program isn't receiving data? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What _specifically_ is not happening? Are you _positive_ that your `OnDataReceive()` method isn't being called? There's nothing in the code you posted that would suggest any mechanism for any other code to be notified that some data has been received, so it may be as simple as that: you _are_ receiving data, but you never find out because you don't ever do anything with the data. You do have other bugs: creating a new `Decoder` on each receive, and allocating insufficient space for your character buffer, to name a couple. But if you want help with the specific problem, post a good code example

Comment: Actually I've tried adding a breakpoint on `OnDataReceive()` so that when this line is called: `_pfnCallBack = new AsyncCallback(OnDataReceived);` I can jump over to see what's happening inside the method. But Visual Studio isn't stepping in. Isn't `bool hasReceived` a flag to let me know I have received data? And also the data I've received is stored `string received` which is called in the main program in this line: `Console.WriteLine("Message from server: {0}", _client.received);`.

Comment: If your receive callback isn't being called, then your socket never receives any data. That would be your primary issue right there. As for the `hasReceived` field, that won't stay set to `true` long enough for any code to notice. Since you didn't bother to post the code that is supposed to respond to received data, I can't say anything more specific than that, but first you have to figure out why the receive callback isn't even being called.